# How to launch command line Java code inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, command-line-interface, launch

I have a Java program which is executed through the basic command line interface. I am wondering about put it in a window JFrame. Is it possible?
How can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what You want... Do you want a "console-emulator" in a JFrame, where you can type commands to your program and read responses?

Comment: I think he has a console application ( without GUI ), and he wants to expose it's functionality through the GUI.

Comment: That's right. I simply want to use a JFrame as "console-emulator", as KarlP said.

Answer (score 1):

If you want command line inside a jFrame I think it is not a good idea. If the JFrame is started that means the program is already started. You have to start the program using command line or running a executable jar file.So there is no meaning in what you are going to do.

If you want to see your output inside a JFrame rather than in the command line, that can be done. You can look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) for details of swing programmimng

Comment: I don't mind to start the program using the CLI before call the JFrame.

Comment: If you use a JFrame you won't actually use CLI to start the Frame. Instead you can just double click the .jar file and run it.
If you want the real output in a JFrame you can add it to a JFrame. Look the above mentioned link for java Swing Programming tutorial.

Comment: I just want to launch the program by 1 click. Can I create a *.jar file which run the program in CLI?